# Erroe while using pip,

Tags: python, pip, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia-jetson

I am using ubuntu 14.04 on a jetson TK1 board, I am new with linux, trying to install jupyter notebook and tensorflow. Unable to use pip and python.

While checking for the pip version by writing either of the code

```
pip -v

pip --version
```

this gives me error,

```
ubuntu@tegra-ubuntu:~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip._internal.models.target_python import TargetPython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/models/target_python.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import normalize_version_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError("Python 3.5 or later is required")
RuntimeError: Python 3.5 or later is required
```

Comment: The error is clear - you need to install `python 3.5` or later for this version of `pip`

Comment: I'm voting to close this, the error message is self-explanatory, never mind the fact that looking it up on google returns plenty of information.

Comment: @AMC I have tried all of that and I also have installed python 3.5

Answer (score 1):

You are running python3.4 and the minimum required is 3.5 so just uninstall 3.4 and install 3.5

Comment: I tried that but it is not working, I think there is some problem with pip but I am not getting it..!!!